# i am try many things but my site cookie as not unset

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie, unset

my site under domain like this: `www.123.com/new`

full site code under the new folder include index page.

i am set the cookie in in remember me click cookie is create

cookie code like this

```
setcookie("cookie_name",$_SESSION['useremail'],time()+3600);
setcookie("cookie_id",$_SESSION['userid'],time()+3600);
```

and cookie unset code on click logout button this.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie_id'])){
    setcookie('cookie_name','',0, '/','studentsponge.com',0);
    setcookie('cookie_id','',0, '/','studentsponge.com',0);
}
```

i am try multiple code for unset cookie like

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie_id'])){
    setcookie('cookie_name','',time()-3600, '/');
    setcookie('cookie_id','',time()-3600, '/');
}
```

but cookie is not unset.

but i am try this code

```
unset($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);
unset($_COOKIE['cookie_id']);
```

its only unset cookie for logout page not full site

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's a good idea to format properly your post before posting it if you want someone to read it.

Comment: You should use exactly the same parameters for path and domain when unsetting cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a

```
ob_start();
session_start();
```

at beginning of your file?
It should help you.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/students/public_html/beta/inner/logout.php:1) in /home/students/public_html/beta/inner/logout.php on line 6

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/students/public_html/beta/inner/logout.php:1) in /home/students/public_html/beta/inner/logout.php on line 7

Comment: you cannot cal header() when you have already outputted something, reading material http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php